# A Mass of Three

Tags: rebus

[image]

Hint 1

> The object after the minus sign in a place

---

<sup>The answer is a big hint for [Which family member doesn't belong?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/which-family-member-doesn-t-belong?)</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please upvote [pacoverflow's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74026/a-mass-of-three/74173#74173) as well, without his help I would have never gotten to this answer.

The first part...

> Guava fruit in a Bag - Baguava

The second part...

> the U.S. state of Virginia (VA)

As a result...

> BAGUAVA - VA = BAGUA
>
> [Bagua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua) which are eight symbols used in Taoist cosmology to represent the fundamental principles of reality.  This point is further enforced by the name of the puzzle (The mass of three) which eludes to the trigram (mass = grams/ 3 grams = trigram).

Note...

> this is also a large hint for [Sensoray's other puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/which-family-member-doesn-t-belong?)

Comment: nice work! For the first part I was thinking ___ in ___, "in" kinda sounds like "and", so you put them together.

Answer (score 8):

After 3 days, I think it's time for a partial answer.

The fruit in a bag is a:

> guava

The thing on the right is:

> the U.S. state of Virginia (VA), horizontally squeezed

Note:

> I'm not sure the bag and the horizontal squeezing are relevant - it might just be that the OP wanted to prevent reverse image searches.

Therefore:

> GUAVA - VA = GUA, which is 3 letters and could fit the title.
>
> What is "GUA" though?  Perhaps the letters need to be rearranged to "AUG", which is short for August, and that could be the hint to the [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71446/which-family-member-doesn-t-belong?) linked by OP, which they indicated may be related to astrological signs.

Comment: Dead on so far, +100 if I could. The main word is more than 3 letters, the title is a different sort of hint. The horizontal squeezing was to represent the shorthand of the location. The bag is definitely relevant, you have all the pieces, just gotta put it all together now :]

Comment: If I were you I would edit it to be rot13(onthn)...

Comment: @Jim You can post that as an answer, I wouldn't have come up with it. Sensoray also said "main word" suggesting that the answer might be more than one word.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> Eries

Reasoning

> Groceries - gross(goo/slime) = erie(s)

So

> It might hint at the great lake Erie?

Comment: Wow.. To be honest, I never looked at the 'hint' of the hint.. But great great answer

Comment: Ahh the minus object is a specific thing (I think slime might be more blob like?), and I'd have put more objects in the bag if it was groceries. That item is specific too :)

Comment: @Sensoray, could the second thing be rot13(zbyq)? :)

Comment: Nope, perhaps less of a thing, and more of a place ;)

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here, but I really like this puzzle.

> LMNABAGMNUSFR

Because

> Lime in a bag = LMNABAGMNUSFR

&

> '-' = MINUS

&

> Fire = FIRE

And so the reasoning..

> The letters that belong among all 3 : IE : Therefore the rest are, to your hint, not belonging

Further reasoning for answer :

> I was more focused on the `Rebus` tag I think

Comment: Ahh thats not a lime or fire, but that IS a bag +1 and thanks!